# Disable connection to data source in BIRT Designer

Tags: java, dataset, database-connection, datasource, birt

I'm using BIRT Designer in Eclipse, just to make a small change in the query of a data set. I do it like this: open Outline view > expand report node > expand Data Sets node > right click on a data set > Edit.

But I've no access to the database from here. I'll have access to it just when I'll put the .rptdesign on the Tomcat server to test it.

By default when editing a data set BIRT connects to the data source specified... hence in my case tries to connect to the DB and finally raises an exception. It doesn't allow me to make my change (adding a new column in my case).

**Is it possible to disable this automatic connection to the data source?**

Comment: Not sure I understand how you don't have access to the database?  Did you create a datasource?

Comment: @JamesJenkins I had access to db when I created the data source.. but now I have not... simply for network reasons :)

Answer (score 1):

Open your report design as xml, either with BIRT or a text engine.

Modify the SQL in the XML.

It should be just past

```
<xml-property name="queryText">
```

This will bypass all the checks, and let you save ANY modifications.

Comment: It was the first thing I tried. But after this change the data set remains the same; so I right-click on it > Refresh... after a long wait, I see the data set looses its children fields in Outline view, as if there was some problem. In fact if you search any already existing DB field in the XML you can see it appears many times, not just in the query.. So I should insert the new field in many places in the XML, imitating the other existing fields, but I think it's not so reliable...

Comment: If you open the report with a text editor, edit it, save the file, and open it with BIRT.  I can not image how could not be updated, unless you don't have write permissions to the drive it is stored on.  The SQL only occurs once in my XML. But if you want it to show up on the report, you will of course need to update the table, all of which you may need to do in XML as well.